# OData $Expand with 1-many relation gives Argument do not match exception

Tags: odata, automapper, expand

Am facing an issue with OData Expand.  Have basic two entities, one is Parent and the other is Children entity. Relationship between Parent to Child is 1-N.

Also have same **mapper** for its corresponding dtos.   .NetCore APi application has **EFcore**, **automapper**. ***All are of the latest version***. Sample is available here at https://github.com/shoguns6/ODataIssue

The issue:
APi works fine if it gets the Parent dto. But the moment i specify the $expand=children in the Api, it gives the ever famous 'Arguments do not match' error.

The expectation:  Parent and its children to be retrieved and displayed to user/browser.

Have seen many post related to the same issue and they claim to have given the solution. But with the latest version of all (EFCore, Autommaper, .Netcore) the issue still exist.

Could you please let me what mistake am making here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this link. This is a known issue and there is nugget available for the same. 
Trick is to effectively define the mapper and use this library https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping/issues/60